# Lilypond: how to force a new page between each piece?

Tags: lilypond

Irish traditional music is played in sets of tunes.  In my score I would like to take new page between each tune.

I have googled, smoogled, froogled, zoogled and kfwoodled :-(

I have tried adding a \breakPage a various points.  No joy.

I need the midi files to play automatically, one after the other.

Here is a slimmed example:

```
    \version "2.22.0"
    \pointAndClickOff
    \header {
      title =  "The lads of Laois Set"
      encodingdate =  "2022-09-26"
      encoder =  "abc2xml version 226"
      source =  "My arrangement from various sources"
    }
    
    between = {r4}
    
    lads_of_laois =  \relative e' {
      \tempo 4 = 100 
      \break
      \repeat volta 2 {
        \time 2/2  \key d \major %%% | % 1
        e8 [ b8 ] b4 e8 [ g8 fis8 e8 ] %%% | % 2
      }
    }
    lads_of_laois_chords =  \chordmode { 
      \set noChordSymbol = ""
      \repeat volta 2 {
        e8:m5 r8 r4 r8 r8 r8 r8 %%% | % 2
      }
    }  
    lads_of_laois_final = {
      <<
        \new ChordNames {
          \set chordChanges = ##t
          \lads_of_laois_chords
        }
        \new Voice = "one" { \lads_of_laois }
      >>
    }
    \score {
      \lads_of_laois_final
      \header {
        piece = "lads_of_laois"
        
      }
      \layout {
        indent = #0
        line-width = #180
        ragged-last = ##t
      }
    }
    
    \header {
      title =  "Reel for Grace"
      encodingdate =  "2022-09-30"
      encoder =  "abc2xml version 226"
    }
    graces =  \relative c {
      \tempo 4 = 100
      \break
      \repeat volta 2 {
        \time 4/4  \key d \major 
        \partial 8*1 fis'8
        d fis fis fis a d fis a
      }
    } 
    
    graces_final = {
      <<
        \new ChordNames {
          \set chordChanges = ##t
                    %no_chords      \graces_chords
        }
        \new Voice = "one" { \graces}
      >>
    }
    \score {
      \graces_final
      \header {
        piece = "graces"
      }
      \layout {
        indent = #0
        line-width = #180
        ragged-last = ##t
      }
    }
    
    stone_of_destiny =  \relative b' {
      \tempo 4 = 120
      \break
      \repeat volta 2 {
        \time 4/4  \key g \major %%% | % 1
        b8 [ d8 d8 b8 ] g4 b8 [ d8 ] %%% | % 2
      }
    }
    
                    % The score definition
    stone_of_destiny_chords = \chordmode {
      \set noChordSymbol = "" 
    }
    
    stone_of_destiny_final = {
      <<
        \new ChordNames {
          \set chordChanges = ##t
                    %    \stone_of_destiny_chords
        }
        \new Voice = "one" { \stone_of_destiny}
      >>
    }
    
    \score {
      \stone_of_destiny_final
      \header {
        piece = "stone_of_destiny"
      }
      \layout {
        indent = #0
        line-width = #180
        ragged-last = ##t
      }
    }
    
    \score {
      \unfoldRepeats
      {
        \lads_of_laois_final
        \lads_of_laois_final
        \lads_of_laois_final
        \between
        
        \graces_final
        \graces_final
        \graces_final
        \between
        
        \stone_of_destiny_final
        \stone_of_destiny_final
        \stone_of_destiny_final
      }
      \midi{}
    }
```

I have tried adding \breakPage in \lads_of_laois and \lads_of_laois_final.

Comment: *I have googled, smoogled, froogled, zoogled and kfwoodled :-(* Interesting. The first hit i my search engine was [4.3.2 Page breaking](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.23/Documentation/notation/page-breaking), the manual page that holds the answer to your question. Google must have had a bad day.

Comment: There's also the [Lilypond index](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/lilypond-index) that can help a lot in your searches.

Answer (score 2):

The command you're looking for is `\pageBreak`.  I don't know how to play one MIDI file after another (except in a MIDI player) so the other choice is to have one, big MIDI file, like this:

```
\version "2.24.0"

\score {
  { 
    %Song one
    c''4 4 4 4 
    \pageBreak 
  
    % Song two
    d''4 4 4 4
  }
  \layout {}
  \midi {}
}
```

But the problem there is that you don't have individual titles.  There are lots of ways to approach this and if you update you question and give more details, we can help more.

Comment: You may also use `\pageBreak` between scores in the same book/file.